# Error running outguess on Linux terminal in windows

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cryptography

So far I was able to get outguess installed on my Ubuntu distribution running under WSL by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-install -y outguess
```

Both commands worked fine. After, I tried running

```
outguess -r input.jpg output.txt
```

and the error

```
Can't open input file 'input.jpg': fopen: Permission denied
```

shows. I've looked on google and a few forums but there is no definitive answer to this. Can anyone help?

Results from `stat input.jpg`:

Size: 29279           Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 2814749767501679  Links: 1
Access: (0000/----------)  Uid: ( 1000/ useradd)   Gid: ( 1000/ useradd)
Access: 2021-01-12 15:51:40.838042800 -0800
Modify: 2021-01-12 15:51:40.838042800 -0800
Change: 2021-01-12 16:08:38.637902400 -0800'

Comment: Are you doing this in the NTFS filesystem, or the linux filesystem?

Comment: Also, run `stat input.jpg` and add the results to the question if you would.  You can replace any username's that show up if needed.

Comment: @Panki yes this is on my main C: NTFS drive

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I posted the results just now :)

Comment: `Access: (0000/----------)` indicates that you don't have permissions to access the file, so you can rule out any specific `outguess` problem.  Are you able to access other files on C: in WSL?  By default, WSL maps Windows/NTFS permissions to Linux per [this spec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions#drvfs-file-does-not-have-metadata-default).  Is this the default mount for `/mnt/c` or have you made any changes (through `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/wsl.conf`, or mounting manually)?

Comment: If you aren't able to access other C: files, try `umask 0022` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds no I haven't made any changes to the linux files, I also tried the umask 0022 and that didn't work either. I just read the link you sent and i'm going to try updating the wsl.conf file.

Comment: Also check out [this question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1352207/windows-wsl-ubuntu-sees-wrong-permissions-on-files-in-mounted-disk) for a similar-sounding problem.  It might be worth checking the detailed permissions and ownership of `input.jpg` just to be sure.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I tried the answers on the links you sent but the result is still the same. The owner of the files is me (not administrators or system).

Comment: Running out of ideas here, but one more try.  `sudo mkdir /mnt/tempC` followed by `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/temp3 -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata,umask=22,fmask=11`.  Then try accessing the directory through `/mnt/tempC` and see if there's any better result.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds it says ' /mnt/temp3: mount point does not exist.
<3>init: (71) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:489: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000
No error information'
is it possible you meant tempC instead of temp3? (this could be a dumb question i'm not very experienced with linux)

Comment: So sorry, I left in a `temp3` by mistake.  Change that one to to `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/tempC -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata,umask=22,fmask=11`

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Ok! So when I run that command it says `-bash: /mnt/tempC: Is a directory`

Comment: That sounds like the command may have been broken across two lines, maybe through a bad copy/paste?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds wdum?

Comment: Confirm that the `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/tempC -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata,umask=22,fmask=11` is being run all on one line.  It sounds like bash is trying to execute `/mnt/tempC` (and likely everything after that) as a command by itself.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Ohhhh, yea i meant that it says `-bash: /mnt/tempC: Is a directory` when i type `/mnt/tempC` not when i type `sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/tempC -o uid=$(id -u $USER),gid=$(id -g $USER),metadata,umask=22,fmask=11`

Comment: I see.  So it sounds like the `mount` worked.  Now you need to to try `outguess` using that mount.  Either `cd /mnt/tempC/Users/username/Pictures/` (or wherever the image is) or reference it directly using something like `outguess -r /mnt/tempC/Users/username/Pictures/input.jpg output.txt`.  Since you said the file is on the C: drive, it should now be accessible (after the `mount`) along the `/mnt/tempC` path.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I still get the same error as the start. I made sure to do `cd /mnt/tempC` and then `outguess -r input.jpg output.txt` after doing the mount process. Idk if this helps but the files on my computer are located in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\mnt\tempC`

Comment: @PK268 Really, really running dry on ideas.  Can you copy the file to your home directory?  My expectation is that a `cp` will fail based on the `stat` command you tried before.  Are you able to read other files on the C: drive inside WSL?  If you create a simple text file in Notepad, for instance, and save it in your Documents folder, can you `cat` it in WSL?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `cp: cannot open '/mnt/tempC/input.jpg' for reading: Permission denied` for the copy and `cat: Test.txt: Permission denied` for reading the text doc. :(